# Efficiently extract matching lines including path and line number?

Tags: powershell, pattern-matching, select-string

The following snippet extracts only the matching lines, I also want the path and line number:

```
Get-ChildItem $thePath\ -Include "*.txt" -Recurse | Get-Content | Select-String  -Pattern 'THE_PATTEN' | Set-Content "output.txt"
```

I tried with this method and still it only extracts the matching lines:

```
Get-ChildItem $thePath\ -Include "*.txt" -Recurse | Get-Content | Select-String  -Pattern 'THE_PATTEN' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line | Set-Content "output.txt"
```

How can I extract the **path:filename:line number: matching line**?

Comment: Do you need the result in a txt? A csv would do the job much better...

Comment: @T-Me for me txt and csv is fine, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that `Get-ChildItem -Filter` is way more efficient than `Get-ChildItem -Include` (see `help get-childitem`). Next is that `Select-String` accepts files. No need to get the content first. Now just `Select` the properties you need and export your file. (Note that the variable `$match` and `$matches` are system variables so you might not want to use them.)

```
$Patterns = Get-ChildItem $thePath -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse| Select-String  -Pattern 'THE_PATTEN' | select Path,Filename,LineNumber,Line

# Export to csv (usable in excel)
$Patterns | Export-Csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation # -Delimiter ";" #  the delimiter is optinal and depending of your region

# Exporting txt
foreach ($Pattern in $Patterns){
    ('{0} : {1} : {2}' -f ($Pattern.Path),($Pattern.LineNumber),($Pattern.Line)) | Add-Content "output.txt"
}
```

Comment: Thank you:-) However, inside the **foreach** we must **Add-Content** because the **Set-Content** writes new content or replaces the existing content of the file.

Comment: If the **-AllMatches** is used with the **Select-String** like this `$Patterns = Get-ChildItem $thePath -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse| Select-String  -Pattern 'THE_PATTEN' -AllMatches | select Matches,Path,Filename,LineNumber,Line`. Then how we can handle it with the **Export-Csv** command.
With **foreach** it is possible to achieve the matches by using another nested **foreach** for the matches. However, I want to know if it is possible with the **Export-Csv** command.

Comment: @AbdulRahmanSherzad edited to change `Set-Conent` to `Add-Content` as you sugested. What kind of behaviour do you want for `-AllMatches`? Currently when you set the parameter it finds multiple occurrences of the pattern per line but it will just output the line once. Do you want to add a column for the count or to add the line multiple times for each occurrence?

Comment: I want both the line and the column. I could manage it using nested loops, however, I want to know if it is feasible using the **Export-Csv** command. Following works perfect: 
`foreach ($the_pattern in $Patterns) 
{
    foreach ($the_match in $the_pattern.Matches) 
    {
        ('{0};{1};{2};{3};{4}' -f ($the_match -replace "[^0-9]"), ($the_match),($the_pattern.LineNumber),($the_pattern.Path), ($the_pattern.Line)) | Add-Content $output_file
    }
}`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need get-content.  The path is passed over the pipe.  (. is for -path, and *.txt is for -filter for speed)

```
get-childitem -recurse . *.txt | select-string hi

foo2\file3.txt:1:hi
file1.txt:1:hi
file2.txt:1:hi
```

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you can get line number and file name from the output of `Select-String`:

```
ls *.txt | % { Select-String -Path $_ -Pattern "THE_PATTERN" | select-object LineNumber, Line, Path }
```

You'll notice this approach is also a touch faster.

Good luck!

Comment: Actually, the filename and line number are included in the default output view as pointed out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59582116/408817

Comment: @Glenn it looks like you've linked back to this post?

Comment: @AbdulRahmanSherzad, Tobias Weltner had a dope presentation on the performance impacts of reading data and passing it through pipes. Of course, I can't find it to share. Net-net, there was a performance penalty to using pipes. The benefit I was referencing related to piping to fewer command lets.